# how to connect to remote desktop without username and password in VB.net

Tags: remote-desktop

I am in the process of developing a vb.net app 
I need to create a remote desktop in VB.net and without entering username and password each time.

Ex: when pressing a button called "A", it should open a remote desktop connection directly without requiring the username and pass of this A.

Comment: Where does it get the username & password? Is it the same user id as the process is running?

Comment: thank you dears,
Its solved:
Private Sub Button11_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
        Dim objShell, strMachineName, strUserName, strUserPwd
        objShell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
        strMachineName = " "
        strUserName = " "
        strUserPwd = " "
        objShell.Run("cmdkey /generic:" & strMachineName & " /user:" & strUserName & " /pass:" & strUserPwd)
        objShell.run("mstsc /v: " & strMachineName)
        objShell = Nothing
    End Sub